# Using querydsl how can I check against a specific object from a set of objects that result from a One to Many relationship?

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

I have a Person JPA entity, and my Person has multiple addresses (OneToMany relationship from Person to Address). I want to be able to do a query for all people that have a particle zipcode but I'm not sure after looking at the querydsl documentation how to properly handle the collection.

I can access the addresses but I'm not sure what to do with them:

```
QPerson qPerson = QPerson.person;
personDao.findAll(qPerson.addresses._SPECIFICADDRESS_.zip.eq('73130'));
```

How can I get the *SPECIFICADDRESS* I'm looking for?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this

```
QPerson qPerson = QPerson.person;
personDao.findAll(qPerson.addresses.any().zip.eq('73130'));
```

Comment: Looks too simple... will try it as soon as I'm back at a terminal. Thanks!

Comment: This is great. What's really getting me now is I have to get even more specific down a stack of collections with collections... This if really fun figuring out though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can express deeper structures with explicit subqueries. any() creates those internally, and for simple structures it's a good alternative.

Comment: Can you share an example of a subquery in above example where I need to check 2 params instead of just one, zip. For eg : where zip = '73130' and stdCode = '0028' ?? I tried with subquery but I am not able to execute it.